# How to make items from a certain mod undroppable or disappear once dropped?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I'm running a Naruto themed Minecraft SMP server, and I want to prevent the players from giving each other a specific object (the jutsu) from the mod.

How do I make items undroppable or disappear once dropped?

Answer (score 1):

`/kill @e[type=item,name=jutsu]`

Put that in an unconditional, repeating, always active command block. It will kill (disappear) all dropped items with the name "jutsu".

You can also try `/kill @e[type=minecraft:item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:egg"}}]`, but replace `minecraft:egg` with the namespace and id of the item you want to kill. ([source](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/redstone-discussion-and/commands-command-blocks-and/2895532-how-to-kill-a-dropped-item-on-the-ground))